# Binary search implementation conditional confusion

Tags: binary-search

I was solving problems using binary search and I became confused when I saw that in some places people have used `while start < end` but in the algorithm my understanding is that it should be `while start <= end`.

For example, here is a solution to the Leetcode problem *Find Smallest Letter Greater Than Target*:

```
def nextGreatestLetter (self, letters: List[str], target: str) -> str:
    l, r = 0, len(letters)-1

    # cross the border
    if target >= letters[-1]:
        return letters[0]

    while l < r:
        mid = (l+r)//2
        if letters[mid] <= target:
            l = mid+1
        else:
            r = mid
    return letters[l]
```

why haven't we decremented `r = mid - 1` and why is not there `while l <= r`? 
 I am really confused.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I wrote an answer but my computer crashed before I posted it. TL;DR just read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm. The first section shows the "classic" binary search algorithm, then modifications are made to bring it to basically the state shown here, with justification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are implementation details. There are multiple ways of implementing everything.

In this case, the loop condition is `l < r` (not `l <= r` ) because when l == r (i.e., there’s only one element in the search space) then we don’t have to process further and the expected result(ceil) is  the element at position `l`.

And the updation statement  is `r = mid` (not `r = mid - 1`) because that updation is happening when `target < letters[mid]` and we cannot discard the element at mid, based on this condition. Suppose for example the element at *(mid - 1)* could be smaller or equal to the target, in that case our result would be the element at *mid*.

Like I said these are just the implementation details and the same solution could be implemented like this as well:

```
def nextGreatestLetter (self, letters: List[str], target: str) -> str:
    l, r = 0, len(letters)-1

    # cross the border
    if target >= letters[-1]:
        return letters[0]

    while l <= r:
        mid = (l+r)//2
        if letters[mid] <= target:
            l = mid+1
        else:
            r = mid - 1
    return letters[l]
```

This implementation where we're processing the `l == r` case inside the loop is also correct and passes all the test cases on Leetcode.

**PS:**
I'm assuming you've recently started competitive coding, so just a suggestion for you. Do not try to remember the implementation and concentrate on the crux of the algorithm, again because there are multiple ways of implementing the same algorithm.

Comment: With some changes in the while loop can we use l<=r statement Everytime?

Comment: Yes, you can. But then there are chances that you might end up introducing some complex handlings inside the loop. Always try to keep your program simple and easy to understand.